# Java Swing open form on button click

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton, multiple-instances

I am developing a card flip flop game in java Swing(using java swing for 1st time). I am using netbeans, I have a menu like new game.. I want that when the user clicks new game button then the game starts. But i dont know how to do this, like when user clicks button , then in event handling action function,is it like this?

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
  JFrame myframe = new JFrame();
  //and the game functionality here

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing the right thing if you want to have a new window open upon click a button. In your sample code, you need to make the new frame visible.

```
public class NewGame {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Start up frame");
    JButton newGameButton = new JButton("New Game");
    frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    frame.add(newGameButton);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    newGameButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JFrame newGameWindow = new JFrame("A new game!");
            newGameWindow.setVisible(true);
            newGameWindow.add(new JLabel("Customize your game ui in the new window!"));
            newGameWindow.pack();
        }
    });
    frame.pack();
}
}
```